# Can I estimate base sales in a Marketing Mix Model (MMM) with muddled promotional data?

Tags: time-series, python, autoregressive, marketing, dynamic-regression

I am building a [marketing mix model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marketing_mix_modeling) (MMM) for an online casino, but they regularly run promotions and marketing campaigns that overlap. Trying to determine a baseline level of sales has been difficult. I'm not the most experienced with the wide range of programming-assisted statistical methods available for the task, so I've attempted to manage the project using Python-specifically the fbprophet package ([facebook-prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/)) to make this easier for me.

My questions are:

Can I estimate the baseline level of sales if I know specific start and end dates for some of the promotions, but not all of them?

Would I need to create dummy variables for all promotions, or can I just model them like a holiday in fbprophet?

Would I be better off decomposing to separate seasonality, from trend, and other noise to estimate a baseline instead?

I appreciate any guidance I can get.